# html and css - multiple level items display

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I call a service I get a JSON of items which I want to display in the following way:

```
 Main Item
 |
 |----------> Sub Item 1
              |
              |------------> Sub Item 2
                             |
                             |---------------> Sub Item X
```

There might up to 8 level items.

Any ideas on the html css how to build it?

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="main">
        <div> class="subItem">
            // dynamically inserted items
        </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using JSON , then in order to build menus items  you need to loop through the json object and append the html

```
$.each ( jsonobject , function (i , val ) {

// code for dynamically appending sub menus 
});
```